# How to alias Hostnames in Kubernetes Deployment Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-pod

How to alias POD Ip Address with different domain name instead of default name.

```
For Example: 
10.1.1.1 testxyz
```

My output has to be with the new entry like below. I have tried with hostAliases but the problem here is ipaddress will be dynamic when pod scales up. so in that case i can't keep my ip address as static in deployment config yaml file. Moreover i don't have permissions to change the /etc/hosts file with non-root user. Kindly suggest.

```
Output:
    10.1.1.1 testxyz
    10.1.1.1 abc.xyz.com
```

Comment: Do you have a Service definition?  Where do the IP address and the name come from?  Using `hostAliases:` or `/etc/hosts` probably isn't going to be a long-term maintainable solution.

Comment: pods are mutable, even if you not scaling up, pod may die for other reasons and will endup getting different ip. That is the reason all the pods / deployment have to exposed thru service (ClusterIP, NodePort or Loadbalander). All the traffic have to go thru service so no need to worry up internal ip addresses or host names. You will be able to access the app thru service name which is configured in internal DNS.

Comment: @david I am setting pod ip address in env variable with fieldselector as status.IP as part of deployment config

Comment: @bala i tried with service as well. When I start an application with service url and port number it gives me the error as bind exception.. due to that reason I am trying to add route url in etc/ hosts as part of deployment config.. it didn't work it throws an exception if I use env variable in host aliases. Kindly suggest

Comment: This seems like functionality Kubernetes provides already with [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/): define a Service that matches your Pods' labels, and it will automatically forward traffic to a matching pod and have a stable DNS name.  Is there a higher-level use case you're working on that directly needs the pods' IP addresses, and can't use a service?

Comment: No it is not like that. Basically I have explored many options nothing worked for my use case. You are suggesting me to use in deployment config yaml set dnsPolicy set as None and assign nameservers with pod ip address with searches as whichever name I want to keep..

Comment: My service is with https port as 443 and targetport as 2000.. and when my application started with route url and port as 2000 it gives me binding exception.. if I start my application by using route url with 443 then it says permission denied to use 443.. if I start my application with pod name and 2000 port then the application will be up but if I want to communicate from one pod to other it says error as unknown host exception. So my end goal is to communicate between two pods with https

Answer (score 0):

Use a Service with type ExternalName to register arbitrary IPs into a cluster DNS entry.

So you would make a service `testxyz` with the address set to `10.1.1.1` and then use the DNS name `testxyz.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local` in config files.

Comment: I already have one service which is exposed outsidewhich is default clusterIP. If i create one more service with external name it doesn't allow because of clusterIP has to be none. So can you provide me sample yaml definition of the service which should not cause issue with route url

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname shows an example. You do not set the clusterIP field since it doesn't have one.

Comment: In the above example I cannot create two service names with the same name one is with external and other is clusterip

Comment: That is correct, DNS doesn't allow for that.